# Can the .NET garbage collector collect an object that is a member to a class?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a class that contains a pointer to an object inheriting off IDisposable

```
class Foo 
{
    private Bar bar;

    private test() 
    {
        bar = CreateBarFactory();
    }

};
```

bar never is used beyond when it is set, in test();

I'm wondering if the GC is permitted to dispose of bar even if the Foo instance is still around?

if so is there a way I can prevent this?   bar is a pointer to an object that contains a ref count,  if it's Disposed() then the ref is released causing some functionality to be disabled

Comment: To prevent it (if it will happen) you should check out this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx)

Comment: I want to understand it first. you have created an object of bar and assigned it to a instance of bar in foo class. Now if you have an instance of Foo around, and bar is disposed. As per the theory, Foo will not be collected by GC and bar will remain intact and not get disposed.

Answer (score 4):

If the instance of foo is still around (i.e. someone is holding a reference to it.. keeping it alive), bar will not be collected. It will be treated as 'reachable' by the GC i.e. in use.

Members of reachable objects are also considered to be reachable.

Comment: "If the instance of foo is still around, bar will not be collected." - not necessarily! If Foo is unreachable, then Bar can be collected, even while instance methods of Foo are still running (as long as Bar is unreachable from the current state of execution).

Comment: @Porges - By "still around", I meant that Foo is reachable (someone has a reference to it, keeping it alive). Can you explain how 'instance members can be running even though the object is unreachable' case? When would that happen?

Comment: what if (by code inspection) you'd say that Foo is reachable - however an optimizer might be able to determine that the object is only set, and never accessed again.  Would the object then be subject to disposal?

Answer (score 2):

Please don't mix up terminology. C# *does* have pointers, but that's not what you have there. You have a *reference*. Importantly, references *do* affect the garbage collector, whereas pointers, in and of themselves, do not.(*)

So long as the instance of `Foo` is reachable, it's reference to `bar` will keep that object reachable too. If `Foo` and `Bar` have finalizers, then, in the finalizer of `Foo` is the one circumstance where you shouldn't assume anything about `bar` - it may have already been finalized itself.

Even though, as you've indicated, no other method will be called that accesses `bar`, the GC and JIT don't perform this sort of analysis. For object references, the entire object is considered to be reachable, and any references it contains are followed and the objects located similarly are marked as reachable. This has to be done so that Reflection based access to an object will never obtain an invalid reference. This is also why, if your object has allocated a large helper object that you will no longer use, it can be (in this limited circumstance) useful to set the reference to `null`.

The only lifetime analysis that *does* consider what future code will run is the code within a single method body, with respect to the local variables. A local reference variable within a method is not sufficient to keep an object alive if no further references to that variable will occur. This is worked out collaboratively between the JIT and GC.

---

(*) people sometimes think that pointers keep objects alive. This is not strictly true. The act of *pinning*, which can *yield* a pointer, will keep an object alive, but there's nothing stopping you from keeping a pointer beyond the time that the object was pinned. Of course, de-referencing the pointer at any such time would be unsafe...

---

And, another terminology issue:

> I'm wondering if the GC is permitted to dispose of bar

The GC *doesn't* dispose of anything. Disposal occurs when an object implements IDisposable and the user of the object calls `Dispose` on it (either directly or via e.g. a `using` block).

The GC doesn't call `Dispose`. It *may* call a finalizer, if one is defined on an object (and so my warning above would apply) and it then collects the object.

Comment: I understand,  my question really boils down to what is considered reachable.  Is a member of a class, that is never used other than to be set, considered reachable

Answer (score 0):

To work properly with this class, you should inherit it from `IDisposable` iterface and realize method `Dispose()` that will call `bar.Dispose()`. It will garantee that this expansive resource will be freed exactly when it can be freed, not when GC decide to Collect.